# MySQLdb.constants.CR' has no attribute 'SECURE_AUTH

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to connect the `MySQL client` package, but I get this AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: module 'MySQLdb.constants.CR' has no attribute 'SECURE_AUTH'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please add also the code that produces that error also which python version you are using

Comment: and also the MySQLdb version (`print(MySQLdb.__version__)`)